# Should this sentence have a comma?

Tags: grammar, commas, sentence, conjunctions

I'm really unsure how this type of sentence is categorised. My inclination is to replace the comma with 'that'. It certainly feels and looks like a comma splice to me.

- *The pigs are so confident in their control, they feel as if they don't need to justify their actions.*

Answer (score -1):

That is indeed a comma splice, or at least feels enough like one to leave a bad taste in my mouth. You can replace it with the word "that" or better yet, a semicolon:

> The pigs are so confident in their control **;** they feel as if they don't need to justify their actions

> The pigs are so confident in their control **that** they feel as if they don't need to justify their actions

Note:
If you use a semicolon, It may be better to change the word "so" into an adjective of some kind to make the first clause independent, for example:

> The pigs are **very** confident in their control; they fell as if they don't need to justify their actions.

Comment: Thanks for this. I think I was swaying towards this to begin with. However, I don't want to change the meaning of the sentence. The sentence is supposed to have a conversational style, so I think it stands as is.

Comment: No; << The pigs are so confident in their control, they feel as if they don't need to justify their actions. >> is a comma splice where the two clauses are intended as independent clauses. Correct then is << The pigs are so confident in their control; they feel as if they don't need to justify their actions. >> The 'so' here would be [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/so)' sense 11. // But without the semicolon (or dash, say), << The pigs are so confident in their control, they feel as if they don't need to justify their actions. >> the second clause should ...

Comment: be read as a (reduced) _that_-clause, not independent. << The pigs are so confident in their control[,] [that] they feel as if they don't need to justify their actions. >> The comma would be very unusual if 'that' were not deleted, but is arguably justified if 'that' _is_ deleted, with such long clauses. //// Compare 'I am so happy[,] I could cry'.

Comment: I could not fix the colon because it's bolded.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth why not _The pigs are so confident in their control they feel as if they don't need to justify their actions_?

Comment: @phoog Some of us like to breathe (and the comma does make the sentence easier to parse).

Answer (score -1):

"*The pigs are so confident in their control, they feel as if they don't need to justify their actions.*"

This is perfectly good English. It is not a comma splice, but rather is a comma used to mean the English word "that".

Comment: The comma is superfluous.  In German, a comma is required here (even with _daß_), but in English it's better without the comma.